# Deploying django static files in production

Tags: python, css, django, nginx, static

My django application is working well on Ubuntu 14.04 / nginx 1.10 / django 1.10.2 / uwsgi 2.0.14, it can also load static files (js, css, images) as well, but css files is not apply to my website. The following is my configuration.

*application structure*

```
example.com/
├── example.com
├── static (generated by collectstatic)
│   └── css
│   └── js
│   └── images
├── templates
└── website
    └── static (django collected from)
```

*uwsgi setting example.com.ini*

```
[uwsgi]
...
socket=/var/www/example.com/uwsgi.sock
chdir=/var/www/example.com
chmod-socket=664
...
```

*nginx.conf*

```
server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    server_name  example.com;

    charset utf-8;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    error_page  404              /var/www/example.com/template/404.html;
    error_page  500 502 503 504  /var/www/example.com/template/500.html;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass      unix:///var/www/example.com/uwsgi.sock;
        include         uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/example.com/static/;
    }
}
```

*setting.py*

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "website/static"),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    ...
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

After running `./manager collectstatic`, I can access .css files by clicking the source path from web page in browser, and checking the access.log it also returns 200, no any error.log produced.

```
"GET /static/admin/css/base.a846c0e2ef65.css HTTP/1.1" 200
```

Static files is already served by nginx I think, but it does not work in production (work in `runserver`), is there any configuration that I missed or doing woring, or any permission that I should check? Thanks for help.

Comment: is there any error printed in browser console ?

Comment: I am not sure but I think location for `/static/` in nginx should be : `alias /var/www/example.com/website/static/;`

Comment: @Anurag there is no error printed in browser console, but wired thing is that I examine the css folder in sources > sources tab from debug panel (chrome), css file exists but empty text, could be cache issue or?

Comment: @ruddra, I've tried that, after nginx restart, all static files are not accessible, return 404

Comment: @pqteru, /static/admin/css/base.a846c0e2ef65.css is returning css or returning empty?
Settings are seems fine I suspect somehow staticfiles_storage is causing this problem.. can you comment this and try to test?Also did you add middleware of whitenoise ?

Comment: @pqteru well my bad. But atleast you can be sure about is that your previous settings were service statics. But I don't know why css files are being empty

Comment: @Anurag your direction was correct, I did not put whitenoise in middleware, so I changed STATIC_STORAGE to default, then the warning came up `Error: The stylesheet xxx.css was not loaded because its MIME type`, I fixed it by add this `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` in nginx.conf, problem solved. thanks a lot! @ruddra thank you as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion Middleware class was missing,

*setting.py*

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
  ...
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  ...
]
```

*nginx.conf*

```
server {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    ...
}
```

Comment: @pqteru I thought you would also accept this answer ;-)